# Revise function to display currently selected array element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which I'm using to display different versions of the same emoji.

When the code runs, click the image to cycle through the `imgs` array to change the images, or use left / right arrow keys to do the same.

I'd like to revise the `changeImage` function so that below the image, it outputs which number in the array is being displayed.

Ideally it would say e.g. 1/5 if there are 5 versions, then 2/5 and so on as you cycle through.

```js
var imgs = [ "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.5.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.0/assets/svg/1f386.svg"
     , "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.0/png/128/1f386.png" ];

var imgs_count = imgs.length;

function changeImage(dir) {

 var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
 img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];

 var imgver = document.getElementById("versions");
 imgver.src = imgs_count;

}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
 e = e || window.event;
 if (e.keyCode == '37') {
  changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image
 } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
  // right -> show next image
  changeImage()
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <h1> fireworks</h1>

    <div id="slideshow" style="margin:20px 0px -2px 0px; border:1px solid #eee; border-radius:5px; padding:20px; width:235px;">
        <center>
   <img alt="slideshow" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" width="128" height="128" />
  </center>
    </div>
 <div id="versions">1 / 5</div>
```

The problem I have is that I can't work out how to edit the function to achieve that.

I can see I can count the number of elements in the array via `imgs.length` and I have assigned an ID to the DIV (`versions`) in which I'd like the info to appear, but my simple test of replacing the content in the div with a value from the function isn't working.

As well as sorting that, I'd need to work out how to output the position of the currently viewed array element.

Any advice much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these four lines to your `changeImage()` function like this:

```
var versionDiv = document.getElementById('versions');
var x = imgs.indexOf(img.src) + 1; // index of current image plus one
var z = x + "/" + imgs_count; // concatenate the strings
versionDiv.textContent = z; //replace the text in the versions div
```

Or you can make it even shorter by avoiding the creation of extra variables which would reduce the above to just two lines like this:

```
var x= document.getElementById('versions');
x.textContent = (imgs.indexOf(img.src) + 1) + "/" + imgs_count;
```

---

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/andrewl64/pen/gzVBdK

Comment: Thank you @AndrewL - brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

This version involves a minimal change to your code.  It just captures the index you're going to in a variable, and uses that in the display:

```js
var imgs = [ "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.5.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg"
     , "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.0/assets/svg/1f386.svg"
     , "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.0/png/128/1f386.png" ];

var imgs_count = imgs.length;

function changeImage(dir) {

 var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
  var index = ((imgs.indexOf(img.src) || 0) + (dir || 1) + imgs_count) % imgs_count
 img.src = imgs[index]

 var imgver = document.getElementById("versions");
 imgver.textContent = (index + 1) + ' / ' + imgs_count;

}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
 e = e || window.event;
 if (e.keyCode == '37') {
  changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image
 } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
  // right -> show next image
  changeImage()
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <h1> fireworks</h1>

    <div id="slideshow" style="margin:20px 0px -2px 0px; border:1px solid #eee; border-radius:5px; padding:20px; width:235px;">
        <center>
   <img alt="slideshow" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F386.svg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" width="128" height="128" />
  </center>
    </div>
 <div id="versions">1 / 5</div>
```

But perhaps a better idea would be to track the index all along, and not query the DOM to figure out where you are.